# Problem getting value of a ASP.NET form field from httpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have declared a form input in my ASP.NET ascx file:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidServiceType" name="hidServiceType" value="somevalue" />
```

And in the web service / web method, I am trying to get the value of this

```
HttpContext postedContext = HttpContext.Current;
serviceType = postedContext.Request.Form["hidServiceType"];
```

I can dig down into postedContext.Request.Form and see 2 keys one being "hidServiceType" but "serviceType" variable = "";

What am I missing, this seems so trival.

Comment: Where did "serviceType" come from?  I don't see that being declared anywhere.

Comment: When you say "in the web service/web method" does this mean the ascx page is not posting to itself? I assume this is the reason you don't just use a regular server control? I can't think of reasons to have a server page post to a web service, though.

Comment: How are you calling your web service / we method? Most mechanisms people use to call those don't automatically post form variables from the originating page.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just add a runat="server" attribute to your input field and then access it as you do everything else from the code-behind?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what difference this makes?

Comment: It appears that he's posting to a web service.

Comment: In that case, I don't want to sound mean, but I'm not sure you understand what ASP.NET is.  How would you access your form elements normally on a ASP.NET page?  Usually you have <asp:TextBox runat="server" /> input control.  So either switch your <input type="hidden" /> to <asp:HiddenField runat="server" /> or add a runat="server" attribute to your <input type="hidden" /> element.